# How do I create a 1px line in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder, retina-display

Note, I'm looking to make a 1px line, not a 1pt line.  Meaning it should be 1px regardless of screen scale (so 0.5pt on Retina devices).

I can do this programmatically, but can I do it in the Interface Builder?  For example I cannot set a UIView to have a height of less than 1.

If I can do it in IB then I don't have to declare an outlet and manually set the frame in `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: um... then don't do it in IB... you can create custom view that does the drawing and use the custom view?

Comment: Yes I can.  But it would be nice if I can do it in IB to be consistent.  If it's not possible, that's fine.  Seems like it should be possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Draw a single point line in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693531/how-to-draw-a-single-point-line-in-ios)

Comment: Dupe of a number of QA, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22694062/294884

Comment: If you're trying to use them as borders or other things... I think it's better to use `CALayer` (if possible), `UIView`s are not very efficient to use as such thing.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do it? What's the point of having thicker line on non-retina display, and extremely thin line on retina one. (And take into consideration, that in the future, your 1px, could be even thinner,assuming higher resolution iDevices)

Comment: The designers wanted a 1px line.  I think they were trying to mimic Apple's table views that have 1px separators (e.g. Mail -> Inbox).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Add a `0.5` pixel height constraint via Interface Builder:

[image: Xcode 7.3 right down corner: add Height constraint in Pin.]

Answer (score 52):

Just in case someone else comes here wanting to know how it can be done programmatically, heres how you do it:

### Interface Builder

Make a height constraint in IB to the desired view and set the constant to 1.

[image]

Then you will need to CTRL+Drag from the constraint into your custom view or ViewController.

Whenever the Xib is loaded, be it in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad`, you are going to set the constant of the constraint to the scale of the display:

#### Swift

```
onePixelViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1/UIScreen.main.scale
```

#### Objective-C

```
self.onePixelViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1.f/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 43):

I created `NSLayoutConstraint` subclass:

```
class HairlineConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.constant = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Then simply create your view in interface builder, add height constraint

[image: Custom view with height constraint]

and set its class to `HairlineConstraint`.

[image: Set constraint class]

Done.

Comment: Beautiful. Modern. Perfect.

Comment: Wait - what about the problem these days of "it may not fall on an integer pixel" ... ?

Answer (score 27):

By creating this tiny subclass of `NSLayoutConstraint` I'm now able to add 1px lines in IB:

```
@implementation NSLayoutConstraintHairline

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if ( self.constant == 1 ) self.constant = 1/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}

@end
```

Any constraint with a value of 1 can be set to class `NSLayoutConstraintHairline` to make the constant effectively 1px instead of 1pt.

If you ever decide to change the constant to another value, it will just work as any other constraint.

Comment: With xCode6 it can be done even more clear, please see my answer.

Answer (score 27):

With Xcode 6 and introduction of `@IBInspectable` and `@IBDesignable` keywords it is definitely possible and rather simple. No need to subclass/outlet anything.

You can do an extension (category) for NSLayoutConstraint with following code (swift):

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var preciseConstant: Int {
        get {
            return Int(constant * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        }
        set {
            constant = CGFloat(newValue) / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can choose needed constraint in your IB.

[image: IB objects navigator part]

Go to its properties and set the value.

[image: IB properties of NSLayoutConstraint]

In above case it will render a view with 1 px height on 1x, 2x and 3x devices.

Comment: This is cool. But rather obscure that you now have two competing fields specifying the actual `constant` field. Is it guaranteed that the "Precise Constant" always wins from the actual Constant? Now and in the future? I've had my share of bugs that originate in the change of execution order between versions X and Y...

Comment: Well, as long as @IBInspectable is just a simple wrapper around User Defined Runtime Attributes I hope there won't be any problems with that, because they are always set in awakeFromNib() after initial view load using setValue:forKeyPath: ([apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AddUserDefinedRuntimeAttributes.html))

Answer (score 14):

In Swift:

```
@IBOutlet var hairlineConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! {
    didSet {
        hairlineConstraint.constant = 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: This answer was for @2x only devices. At that time @3x was not yet on the market!**

Nowadays, `@mdvs`'s answer seems to be the cleanest.

---

Making 1px line in IB is hard even for retina-only devices. Finally I've achieved it using the `User Defined Runtime Attributes`.

Here's a screenshot for setting the Height Constraint to 0.5 px (which is 1px on retina devices).

[image]

Comment: This breaks on iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: It was meant for the times before iP6 generation has been announced. It's definitely outdated now.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Nevs12 's answer and it's comments, I think it makes more sense to use such thing:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    @IBInspectable var usePixels: Bool {
        get {
            return false // default Value
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                constant = constant / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it is not possible, one must do it programmatically or build a custom view.

Comment: I think it is possible to do this IB-only, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in .xib file. Just edit it as text and set constant="0.5" instead of "1" in your view height constraint

```
<constraints>
<constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="0.5" id="xUN-dm-ggj"/>
</constraints>
```

[In Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9NWb.png)